# Java8 streams and class casting error

Tags: eclipse, java-8, javac

I'm reading a book for Java8 features and it contains a quiz that its solution is the following code:

```
List<Integer> numbers1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> numbers2 = Arrays.asList(3, 4);
List<int[]> pairs = numbers1.stream().flatMap(i -> numbers2.stream().map(j -> new int[]{i,j})).collect(Collectors.toList());
        pairs.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The problem is that the third line causes an error to the compiler with the following message:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<int[]>
```

How can I make the stream to return a `List<int[]>` ?

thx

Comment: Tried this code [here](http://www.compilejava.net/) and it compiled just fine.

Comment: I use Eclipse Luna with JDK1.8.0_31 and generates the posted error.

Comment: Perhaps it's an Eclipse bug. Try to compile it in command line with javac.

Comment: @gfot It compiles fine with javac. Eclipse uses it's own compiler and it's not yet 100% stable with Java 8 as you experienced it. You might report a bug to the Eclipse dev's team.

Comment: Just tested and works using javac. Thanks!